# Determine whether the input matches a specified format

Tags: python, input, format

Is there an option in Python 3 to determine whether the input matches a specified format? For example: the format is `d-dddd-dddd-d` with the `d` standing for a digit (0-9):

```
>>> ('9-9715-0210-0')
True
>>> ('997-150-210-0')
False
```

Comment: You could use a *"regular expression"*, see [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: A starting point would be: https://regex101.com/r/bV8kZ4/2

Comment: Is something like this posible 
    'string = input()
    pattern = \d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d
    result = re.match(pattern, string)'

Comment: @Aleandro why don't you **try it and find out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex would work like this:

```
import re

regex = r'\d-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d'

preg = re.compile(regex)

s1 = '9-9715-0210-0'
s2 = '997-150-210-0'

m1 = preg.match(s1)
m2 = preg.match(s2)

if m1:
    print('String s1 is valid')
else:
    print('String s1 is invalid')

if m2:
    print('String s2 is valid')
else:
    print('String s2 is invalid')
```

You can try the code at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7B2hj0).

The regex you suggested in the comment below your question is just the long version of mine. So that should work, too.

Comment: Note that `{1}` is redundant and a regex [should be in a `r'raw string'`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = "9-9715-0210-0"
split = string.split("-")
if len(split[0]) == 1 and len(split[1]) == 4 and len(split[2]) == 4 and len(split[3]) == 1:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

You could also change string to be an `input` so you can enter input or create a function from this code and run it multiple times.

Comment: That is extremely fragile; it will throw `IndexError` if there are fewer than 3 `-`s, ignores any subsequent `-`-separated groups and doesn't care whether or not the characters in each group are digits.